# Update All other Records Based on a single record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table with a million records. I need to update some columns which are null based on the existing 'not null' records of a particular id based columns. I've tried with one query, it seems to be working fine but I don't have confidence in it that it will be able to update all those 1 million records exactly the way I need. I'm providing you some sample data how my table looks like.Any help will be appreciated

```
SELECT * INTO #TEST FROM (
SELECT 1 AS EMP_ID,10 AS DEPT_ID,15 AS ITEM_NBR ,NULL AS AMOUNT,NULL AS ITEM_NME
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,20,16,500,'ABCD' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,30,17,NULL,NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 2,10,15,1000,'XYZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,30,16,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,40,17,NULL,NULL
) AS A
```

Sample data:

```
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
| EMP_ID | DEPT_ID | ITEM_NBR | AMOUNT | ITEM_NME |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|      1 |      10 |       15 | NULL   | NULL     |
|      1 |      20 |       16 | 500    | ABCD     |
|      1 |      30 |       17 | NULL   | NULL     |
|      2 |      10 |       15 | 1000   | XYZ      |
|      2 |      30 |       16 | NULL   | NULL     |
|      2 |      40 |       17 | NULL   | NULL     |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
| EMP_ID | DEPT_ID | ITEM_NBR | AMOUNT | ITEM_NME |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|      1 |      10 |       15 | 500    | ABCD     |
|      1 |      20 |       16 | 500    | ABCD     |
|      1 |      30 |       17 | 500    | ABCD     |
|      2 |      10 |       15 | 1000   | XYZ      |
|      2 |      30 |       16 | 1000   | XYZ      |
|      2 |      40 |       17 | 1000   | XYZ      |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
```

I tried this but I'm unable to conclude whether it is updating all the 1 million records properly.

```
SELECT * FROM #TEST T
inner JOIN #TEST T1 ON T1.EMP_ID=T.EMP_ID
WHERE T1.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL

UPDATE T  SET AMOUNT=T1.AMOUNT 
FROM #TEST T 
inner JOIN #TEST T1 ON T1.EMP_ID=T.EMP_ID
WHERE T1.AMOUNT IS not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used UPDATE using inner join

```
UPDATE T
SET T.AMOUNT = X.AMT,T.ITEM_NME=X.I_N
FROM #TEST T
JOIN 
(SELECT EMP_ID,MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMT,MAX(ITEM_NME) AS I_N
FROM #TEST
GROUP BY EMP_ID) X ON X.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * into #Test1
FROM #TEST 
WHERE AMOUNT IS NOT NULL
```

**For records validation run this query first**

```
SELECT T.AMOUNT, T1.AMOUNT, T1.EMP_ID,T1.EMP_ID
FROM #TEST T 
inner JOIN #TEST1 T1 ON T1.EMP_ID=T.EMP_ID
WHERE T.AMOUNT IS NULL

Begin Trans

UPDATE T  
SET T.AMOUNT=T1.AMOUNT, T.ITEM_NME= = T1.ITEM_NME 
FROM #TEST T 
inner JOIN #TEST1 T1 ON T1.EMP_ID=T.EMP_ID
WHERE T.AMOUNT IS NULL

rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT EMP_ID,MAX(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT MAX(ITEM_NAME) as ITEM_NAME
           INTO #t
    FROM #TEST
    GROUP BY EMP_ID


UPDATE t SET t.AMOUNT = t1.AMOUNT, t.ITEM_NAME = t1.ITEM_NAME
FROM #TEST t INNER JOIN #t t1
ON t.emp_id = t1.emp_id
WHERE t.AMOUNT IS NULL and t.ITEM_NAME IS NULL
```

Use `MAX` aggregate function to get amount and item name for each employee and then replace `null` values of amount and item name with those values. For validation use `COUNT` function to calculate the number of rows with values of amount and item name as null. If the number of rows is zero then table is updated correctly